# Tensorflow: How to Pool over Depth?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following parameters defined for doing a max pool over the depth of the image (rgb) for compression before the dense layer and readout...and I am failing with an error that I cannot pool over depth and everything else:

```
sunset_poolmax_1x1x3_div_2x2x3_params = \
    {'pool_function':tf.nn.max_pool,
     'ksize':[1,1,1,3],
     'strides':[1,1,1,3],
     'padding': 'SAME'}
```

I changed the strides to `[1,1,1,3]` so that depth is the only dimension reduced by the pool...but it still doesn't work.  I can't get good results with the tiny image I have to compress everything to in order to keep the colors...

Actual Error:

> ValueError: Current implementation does not support pooling in the batch and depth dimensions.

Comment: The error message is pretty much explaining what is happening.

Comment: @etarion  Ah...I was reading it as a logical 'AND': batch AND depth dimensions (instead of what was apparently meant as "batch or depth" dimensions).  So, logically, if I don't pool over one, I should be able to pool over the other. Anyhow, if you had explained what you were saying, that would have made sense, because the error message is pretty much saying something other than what it was intended to mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

tf.nn.max_pool does not support pooling over the depth dimension which is why you get an error.

You can use a max reduction instead to achieve what you're looking for:

`tf.reduce_max(input_tensor, reduction_indices=[3], keep_dims=True)`

The `keep_dims` parameter above ensures that the rank of the tensor is preserved. This ensures that the behavior of the max reduction will be consistent with what the tf.nn.max_pool operation would do if it supported pooling over the depth dimension.

Comment: unfortunately does not happens only with max_pool, but also for conv2d. This is my function `tf.nn.conv2d(img_input, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 3], padding='SAME'), b)` and it give me the same error of @bordeo. I need to keep the color.
I think this is an inefficiency of the conv2d function, isn't it ?

Comment: I know that this was asked a long time ago, but maybe @Kyrol could take a look at `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d`? I agree with @Benoit about preserving the channels on maxpooling.

Comment: This implementation assumes that the pool size is equal to the number of channels, so it collapses all channels into just one. With depthwise pooling, it's better if the pool size is much smaller, like 3. See my answer for an implementation. Also, reduction_indices was renamed to axis, and keep_dims was renamed to keepdims.

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow now supports depth-wise max pooling with `tf.nn.max_pool()`. For example, here is how to implement it using pooling kernel size 3, stride 3 and VALID padding:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

output = tf.nn.max_pool(images,
                        ksize=(1, 1, 1, 3),
                        strides=(1, 1, 1, 3),
                        padding="VALID")
```

You can use this in a Keras model by wrapping it in a `Lambda` layer:

```py
from tensorflow import keras

depth_pool = keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda X: tf.nn.max_pool(X,
                             ksize=(1, 1, 1, 3),
                             strides=(1, 1, 1, 3),
                             padding="VALID"))

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    ..., # other layers
    depth_pool,
    ... # other layers
])
```

Alternatively, you can write a custom Keras layer:

```py
class DepthMaxPool(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, pool_size, strides=None, padding="VALID", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if strides is None:
            strides = pool_size
        self.pool_size = pool_size
        self.strides = strides
        self.padding = padding
    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.nn.max_pool(inputs,
                              ksize=(1, 1, 1, self.pool_size),
                              strides=(1, 1, 1, self.pool_size),
                              padding=self.padding)
```

You can then use it like any other layer:

```py
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    ..., # other layers
    DepthMaxPool(3),
    ... # other layers
])
```

Comment: This works only for 1D or 2D inputs. For 3D inputs, if the channels are the last dimension of the input tensor, you won't get any errors but the operation will not performed. For 3D inputs, as a workaround, you can use a `keras.layers.Permute` layer to move the channel dimension in another position, apply a maxpool3d and then restore the shape back with another permute layer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief example to the original question for tensorflow. I tested it on a stock RGB image of size `225 x 225` with 3 channels.

Import the standard libraries, enable `eager_execution` to quickly view results

```
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

Read image and cast from `uint8` to `tf.float32`

```
x = tf.cast(imread('tiger.jpeg'), tf.float32)
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2]])
print(x.shape)
input_channels = x.shape[3]
```

Create the filter for depthwise convolution

```
filters = tf.contrib.eager.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[3, 3, input_channels, 4]))
print(x.shape)
```

Perform depthwise convolution with `channel multiplier` 4. Note the the padding has been kept to `'SAME'`. It can be changed at will.

```
x = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(input=x, filter=filters, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME', name='conv_1')
print(x.shape)
```

Perform the `max_pooling2d`. Since the output of the pooling layer is `(input_size - pool_size + 2 * padding)/stride + 1` and the padding is `'valid'`, we should get an output of `(225 - 2 + 0)/1 + 1 = 223`.

```
x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=x, pool_size=2, strides=1,padding='valid', name='maxpool1')
print(x.shape)
```

Plot the figures to confirm.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3)
q = 0
for ii in range(4):
    for jj in range(3):
        ax[ii, jj].imshow(np.squeeze(x[:,:,:,q]))
        ax[ii,jj].set_axis_off()
        q += 1
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an excerpt from the book Hands on Machine learning with scikit learn keras and tensorflow.
Keras does not include a depthwise max pooling layer, but TensorFlow’s low-level
Deep Learning API does: just use the tf.nn.max_pool() function, and specify the
kernel size and strides as 4-tuples (i.e., tuples of size 4). The first three values of each
should be 1: this indicates that the kernel size and stride along the batch, height, and
width dimensions should be 1. The last value should be whatever kernel size and
stride you want along the depth dimension—for example, 3 (this must be a divisor of
the input depth; it will not work if the previous layer outputs 20 feature maps, since
20 is not a multiple of 3):

```
output = tf.nn.max_pool(images,
ksize=(1, 1, 1, 3),
strides=(1, 1, 1, 3),
padding="valid")
```

If you want to include this as a layer in your Keras models, wrap it in a Lambda layer
(or create a custom Keras layer):

```
depth_pool = keras.layers.Lambda(
lambda X: tf.nn.max_pool(X, ksize=(1, 1, 1, 3), strides=(1, 1, 1, 3),
padding="valid"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom Keras layer:

```py
class DepthPool(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, pool_size=2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pool_size = pool_size
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        old_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
        num_channels = old_shape[-1]
        num_channel_groups = num_channels // self.pool_size
        new_shape = tf.concat(
            [old_shape[:-1], [num_channel_groups, self.pool_size]], axis=0)
        reshaped_inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, new_shape)
        return tf.reduce_max(reshaped_inputs, axis=-1)
```

Notes:

- there's no `strides` argument: it is assumed to be equal to the pool size
- TensorFlow's `tf.nn.max_pool()` operation supports depthwise pooling (see my other answer), but it only works on the CPU, so this custom layer is generally better